# Where to download stream Benchmark MPI version

Tags: stream, mpi, benchmarking

Could you kindly tell me where I can download the stream benchmark for MPI version? I googled a lot but in the following link, I could just download stream benchmark without mpi. I couldn't find any download link for stream-mpi. 
http://www.nersc.gov/users/computational-systems/cori/nersc-8-procurement/trinity-nersc-8-rfp/nersc-8-trinity-benchmarks/stream/

And no download link here:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the link](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/FTP/Code/Versions/stream_mpi.c)

It was in the [Versions](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/FTP/Code/Versions/) directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is no zip file right? I mean I should create the files and copy the codes one by one into my server, right? no quick way?

Comment: As far as I know, the files in STREAM are self -contained. You should be able to compile a single one. So if all you want is the mpi benchmark, I think you can just copy and paste or transfer the one file. But no, I do not know of a zip.

Comment: I have copied the stream_5-10_posix_memalign.c, stream_mpi.c and stream_mpi.f files. I also modified the Makefile by setting the flags and also by defining stream_mpi_c.exe: stream_mpi.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c stream_5-10_posix_memalign.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) stream_mpi.c -o stream_mpi_c.exe    and the same for fortran. when I want to make it gives me an error on the second line: Makefile:38: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop. The issue is not the spaces actually. Do you have any idea regarding this?